# How to export table into csv file in angular 2

Tags: angular, html-tableextract

How to export data table on my angular application UI into a CSV file or xls spreadsheet. Looking to have a button to be displayed on top of the table clicking on which can do this export. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of `angular2-csv` or `ng-table-to-csv`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv
https://github.com/kollavarsham/ng-table-to-csv

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Amy. I tried both and ended up using Alasql for this.